# Moving from frozen gems to bundlr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a lot of gems (in a Rails 2.3 app) in the vendor/ directory.  These are frozen in using rake.  I'd like to move to Bundlr.

What's the best way of migrating these gems?

Answer (score 0):

Bundler will allow you to install specific versions of your gems: http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html

While I don't know of a way to auto-generate a `Gemfile` from your existing frozen gems, you can definitely do a quick audit of the versions of the gems you are using and then setup a `Gemfile` which will bundle in the exact same gems.

Here's info on setting up Rails 2.3 with Bundler: http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

Remember to remove all of your `config.gem` declarations from your environments. These should all be specified in the `Gemfile` now in the right format for bundler.

If you want your new gems to be stored in your repository for easy access (and faster install/deployment), check out `bundle package`: http://gembundler.com/bundle_package.html